# Jasmine for C# and/or Java

Tags: c#, java, jasmine

Jasmine is a nice unit testing framework for JavaScript. It not only tests your code, it provides a nice way to document it by:

- Using a fluent BDD-ish way to define tests that in itself almost reads like a documentation
- The test report reads like a documentation too

I'm wondering if anything comparable exists for C# and/or Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just came across [NJasmine](https://github.com/fschwiet/DreamNJasmine) on GitHub.  I've never used it but thought this might help others like myself that want the awesome of Jasamine in C# unit tests.

From the GitHub:

> NJasmine is a RSpec-ish test language inspired by the javascript test library Jasmine (https://github.com/fschwiet/DreamNJasmine) for C# / .Net programming.

```
given("some preconditions", () => {

    var range = 10;

    when("the system under test is ran", () => {

        var sut = new SystemUnderTest();

        bool score = arrange(() => sut.Fire(range));

        then("win!", () => {

            expect(() => score);
        });
    });
});
```

> Available on Nuget: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NJasmine

Again, I can't vouch for this as I haven't used it, but I hope this will help others make informed decisions.

HTH

Answer (score 6):

[JUnit 5](http://junit.org/junit5/) will be BDD-like, with @DisplayName, @Nested, and so on. You can have a look [at the documentation](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested).

The GA release is not here yet, but it should arrived soon (announced for late 2016).

Comment: It's great to see JUnit having build in support for it now. Making it possible to do BDD TDD in Java through the  "default" testing framework

Answer (score 4):

**[Oleaster](https://github.com/mscharhag/oleaster)** is a Java testing framework with clean simple syntax, extensively using Java 8 arrow functions. It is executed using JUnit runner.

Code sample from hompage:

```java
@RunWith(OleasterRunner.class)
public class OleasterIntroductionTest {{
    describe("A suite", () -> {
        it("contains a spec with an expectation", () -> {
            expect(40 + 2).toEqual(42);
        });
    });
}}
```

Comment: What's the funny double-brace syntax? I admit I haven't seen it before. Is it new with Java 8, too?

Comment: The block directly nested into class is called **instance initialization block** and is executed before constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block or [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for details. It was introduced before Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

A very popular framework for testing Java (and Groovy) is [Spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/), whose tests also read like written specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Cucumber-JVM](http://c0deattack.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/cucumber-jvm-with-cucumber-java-cucumber-junit-example/) for implementing BDD. It is Java based but also works with JVM-based languages (Scala, Groovy).

If using a continuous integration system such as Jenkins, there is a reporting plugin called [Cucumber Reports](https://github.com/masterthought/cucumber-reporting) available.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent for Java would be [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/) is a port of Ruby's RSpec BDD.

```
@RunWith(Ginkgo4jRunner.class)
public class MyTests {

  private SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest;

  private int range;

  private bool score;

  {
    Describe("SystemUnderTest", () -> {
      BeforeEach(() -> {
        systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest();
      });
      Context("#Fire", () -> {
        JustBeforeEach(() -> {
          score = systemUnderTest.Fire(range));
        });
        Context("given a range", () -> {
          BeforeEach(() -> {
            range = 10;
          });
          It("should return a winning score!", () => {
            assertThat(score, is(true));
          });
      });
    });
  }
}
```