# instanceof : Invalid Token

Tags: java

Whenever I try to put an **"instanceof"** keyword it says it's an **unexpected token** . 
For information I ham using **ArchLinux** with an **AUR java package**.

```
public class TestZones {
    class A{}
    class B extends A{}
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    if(b instanceof A){}
}
```

This syntax does it on the if.

Comment: Please add a code example

Comment: Show us the relevant code in which this is occurring please.

Comment: Refer to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You can't just put code anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement does not appear to be within a method or an [initialization block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987428/2970947),

```
public void doStuff() {
  if(b instanceof A){ // <-- like so
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  if(b instanceof A){ // <-- like so
  }
}
```

Comment: @Traxys Thanks for editing your question, but my answer still appears to be correct. You aren't performing your test within a method or an initialization block. You'd get the same error on `if (1 == 1)` (or there's more code you need to post).

Comment: Ok so that I did not think about , thanks for this problem that tortured my head for quite a bit :)