# App unable start- null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

The app crashes and is unable to start. The code compiles without error but crashes as soon as i run the emulator to attempt to test the application. Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

***This is my MainActivity.java***

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import info.datatool.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Convert", "Data Ranges", "" };
{

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

***This is my CatLog after attempting to run the application and it crashes***

```
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.overworldinnovations.datatool/com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
09-14 17:48:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 11 more
09-14 17:53:20.504: I/Process(1168): Sending signal. PID: 1168 SIG: 9
```

Comment: When you are posting stack traces, it always helps if you identify the line(s) of your code where the exception is thrown. Please point out which is line 25 of MainActivity.java

Comment: i apologize. This is the bit of code that starts at line 25----- // Initialization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move this initializer block to `onCreate()` in your activity:

```
{

    // Initialization

    ...
}
```

Instance initialization (`<init>` in stacktrace) is too early to call activity methods such as `findViewById()`.

---

Since you don't yet have an `onCreate()` and need one, you can turn the initializer into one. Replace the opening `{` with something like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_id);

    // Initialization

    ...
```

where `some_layout_id` refers to the XML layout you want to use as the content view for this activity.

Comment: How does @user3681591 initialize the code? What type of syntax is that?

Comment: @valbertos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block

Comment: Thank you @laalto, I only knew the static initialization