# Why is this Java program showing no error?

Tags: java

Consider the below code,

I forgot to define the method name, just the code within the block.

```
public class Demo {

    {
    Apple ap;
    // Display price of Winesap.
    System.out.println("Winesap costs " + Apple.Winesap.getPrice()
            + " cents.\n");
    // Display all apples and prices.
    System.out.println("All apple prices:");
    for (Apple a : Apple.values())
        System.out.println(a + " costs " + a.getPrice() + " cents.");
    }

}
```

is it because blocks{} in java defines a scope?

> A block {} defines the scope in Java. Each time you start a new block, you are creating a new 
>       scope. A scope determines what objects are visible to other parts of the program. It also 
>       determines the lifetime of these objects. Many other computer languages define 2 general category 
>       of scopes : global and local.

Comment: You just asked an answer :)

Comment: You've just posted an answer, we should post the question.

Comment: It is an [instance initialization block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block) ([more at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)).

Comment: @Suresh Atta: I am just guessing what use this block will have...

Comment: we need more of you ;), why would i ask? just answer directly

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ hhahahaha you're exactly right. How weird is that? :P

Comment: Even Java defines actually 3 categories of blocks. *static blocks*, *instance level blocks* and *method local blocks*.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari Congrats. Jon Skeet came for your rescue :)

Comment: @icza: that's a nice link to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got there is an *instance initializer*, as described by [section 8.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6).

It's executed before the body of any constructor when an instance is created - just like field initializers.