# The assignment to variable [Something] has no effect

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I get this warning, what does it mean?

> The assignment to variable name has no effect.

I also get the same error for all 3 fields. The full code is below:

```
public class Module {

    private String name;
    private int bind;
    private Category category;

    public Module(String name,int bind,Category category) {
    }{
        this.name = name; // The assignment to variable name has no effect
        this.bind = bind;
        this.category = category;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem, extra braces:

```
public Module(String name,int bind,Category category) {
}{ // <<<
    this.name = name;
    this.bind = bind;
    this.category = category;
}
```

It should be:

```
public Module(String name,int bind,Category category)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.bind = bind;
    this.category = category;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public Module(String name,int bind,Category category) {
}{
```

there's an extra pair of braces, so your code is practically not inside the constructor.

Your code will be run ***before*** the constructor as an ["instance initialization block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block), therefore, these naming refers to the instances of your class, not to the constructer arguments.

Comment: In future, please vote close as a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answers given.

The code you have is perfectly valid. In effect, you created a constructor that does not assign any variable :

```
public Module(String name,int bind,Category category) {
}
```

and below you created an [initializer code block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) that is called by every constructor :

```
{
 this.name = name;
 this.bind = bind;
 this.category = category;
}
```

This block effectively assigns every local variable to itself which causes the compiler to warn you about that.