# Java curly braces syntax without method or static block?

Tags: java

I am confused about a Java code block I don't what it represents.

```
public class Person {



    { // Here that is this ? Is this static code, apparently it is not? is it anonymous static class ?

        System.out.println(this.getClass());
        System.out.println(getAge());

    }

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an instance initializer block.

Comment: See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block

Comment: @T.J Crowder, Thanks, I also saw the question and wanted to close as duplicate.