# .add() method not working for ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm learning Java and I'm stuck with a little problem.
The method .add() applied to my ArrayList object doesn't want to compile.
I tried the same thing (with different parameters) on another program and it is working fine, so there's clearly something I've done wrong this time, but I can't figure out what. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
private List<String> science = new ArrayList<String>();
science.add("geography");
```

This bit of code gives me the following error:

- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
- Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
   QualifiedName
- Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
- Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
   MethodHeaderName

This is the entire code of the program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Facolta {

        private String nome;
        private int facilities, tipo;
        private List<String> science = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<String> other = new ArrayList<String>();

        science.add("geography");


        public Facolta(String nome, int facilities, int tipo) {
            this.nome = nome;
            if (science.toString().contains(nome)) {
                this.tipo = 2;
            }
            else if (other.toString().contains(nome)) {
                this.tipo = 1;
            }
            this.facilities = facilities;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public void getFacilities() {
            if (tipo == 1)
                System.out.println("Lab number: " + facilities);
            else if (tipo == 2)
                System.out.println("Library number: " + facilities);
            else
                System.err.println("Facility not available.");

        }

        public void setFacilities(int facilities) {
            if (facilities < 3) this.facilities = facilities;
            else System.err.println("Facility not specified.");
        }

}
```

Comment: Sangwon Choi's answer is what you need to fix that, but your class has some design flaws: (1) the constructor has the parameter `tipo`, but it's never used. (2) What happen when `name` doesn't match with the contents of `science` or `other`? (3) I can imagine `science` and `other` as types of `Facolta`, so, they should be outside; and so on... Anyway, I guess you're learning, so, keep going :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just put *any* kind of code in *any* place of your class.

In this case, you could move that line **into** your constructor for example.

You could also use an init block; so just put braces

```
 { 
   sciences.add("blocked");
 }
```

right there (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block) for details on that).

But the real thing is: I guess that `science` list contains the subjects some student is supposed to take. So it should be rather a **parameter** of your constructor; instead of **hardcoding** that string within your source code!

The alternative would be to make that list a real "constant"; like this:

```
private final List<String> SCIENCES_THAT_GIVE_TIPO =  Arrays.asList("geography", "whatever");
```

to make your *intention* clearer!

And beyond that: using *Strings* to denote such things is of course simple and straight forward; but a rather bad design. So, just in case you want to play around a bit; you might want to read about Java [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html); and then consider to turn your different sciences into an Enum!

Comment: So, if "science" and "other" are going to be lists of final strings that'll never change, is it better to declare them in the main method?

Comment: @ClaudioLavacca That really depends; I updated my answer to give a hint.

Answer (score 2):

anyway,

```
List<String> science  = Arrays.asList("geography", "geography2");
```

This works for your condition

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect.

science.add("geography") - should be done in a method or in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I suggestion for ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> science =new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("geography", "geography2"));
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would use the specific class type for the variable instead of using the interface type? (and why are you calling it mStatus?)

Comment: sorry for the misconception, I thought it was ArrayList. I had the same problem in ArrayList, so I coped it from my code that's why I am calling it as mStatus.