# Java Executor Service Is Not Processing Parallely

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am attempting to run multiple services parallely using ExecutorService. But i failed to execute parallely.

I have written **java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1)** to wait one minute in Service1 class.

But Service2 is processing only after Service1 processed.

Below is my code snippet, Kindly correct me/code if my understand about ExecutorService is wrong

```
public void startService() {

    try {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        service.submit(new Service1());
        service.submit(new Service2());
        service.submit(new Service3());

        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        System.exit(0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class Service1 implements Callable<Object> {

    {
        try {
            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Service2 implements Callable<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Service 2 "); // It prints after 1 minute only.
        return null;
    }
}

public class Service3 implements Callable<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Service 3 "); 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works for me

Comment: more precisely, Service1 starts before Service2, but ends after

Comment: Sorry, when i put as global sop { }. Its not working

Comment: where is `Service3` ?

Comment: @Siva "when i put as global sop { }" -- I'm not sure what you mean with "global sop {} ", but why don't you test that the code that you post reproduces the problem? That saves everyone a lot of time. And make sure that it compiles.

Comment: @Erwin . Really sorry & Please see my edited code now.

Comment: @niceman - Please see my updated code

Comment: @Siva move your code from initialization block to call method in Service1

Comment: Better suggestion that explains what you are doing in the {} block: [What is an initialization block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block)

Comment: @rvit34.. Noted & Thanks.

Comment: @ Erwin Bolwidt.. Noted & Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
{
    try {
        java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

is a constructor, and it is called by the main thread when it's doing new Service1().
So yeah, it must complete before it has a chance to submit the services.

UPDATE:

In your original post, the sleep was in the call method, and it worked. Now, your Service1 is equivalent to:

```
public class Service1 implements Callable<Object> {

    public Service1() {
        try {
            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And only the call method is run by the executor. the Service1 instance cannot even be submitted before the constructor completes.

Comment: Sorry Maurice. I am new thread, can you please elaborateif you dont mind.

Comment: You are saying that Service2 will invoke only after Service1 initialization completes right?

Comment: @ Maurice Perry. I understood it. Thank you very much.