# In Java, initializing and accessing array inside a method?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 class example{

   int[] quiz = new int[] { 10 , 20 };    //location 1

     public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] test = new int[2];   // location 2
test[0] = 2;
test[1] = 3;
 // other code
}
```

The above code run correctly. However the code below causes an error. My reasoning for the error is since `quiz` is declared outside the method it needs to be initialized immediately. However I am not sure if this is a correct explanation.

```
class example{

    int[] quiz = new int[2];    //location of error
    quiz[0] = 10;
    quiz[1] = 20;


     public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] test = new int[2];   // location 2
test[0] = 2;
test[1] = 3;
 //other code
}
```

Comment: suppose this [post](http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2013/10/static-blocks-vs-instance-blocks.html) would be helpful to you to get a better expalnation.

Comment: Declare and initialize on the same line: `int[] quiz = {10, 20};` or initialize your array within a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need an [*initialization block*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block) to do it the second way,

```
int[] quiz = new int[2];
{
    quiz[0] = 10;
    quiz[1] = 20;
}
```

Comment: Well explained, Elliott.