# Does JavaFX have a function similar to onInit?

Tags: java, windows, angular, javafx, view

I'm learning how to build windows apps using JavaFX. I was wondering if JavaFX has something similar to Angular's OnInit function where I can make method calls before the view is actually loaded.

Comment: Java has [initialization blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987428/2970947).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Comment: You can write something in the constructor.
Or, you can write a method to call it before having your view shown.

Comment: I'm actually navigating to the view from the root view, so I wrote a method to get/set the info that was needed, that could then be called while setting up the view.