# Having a bit of trouble understanding inheritance? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I've been trying to teach myself inheritance using java, but I am really confused and it seems online youtube videos/looking at previous questions are not helping at all. I tried the practice problems on this website: http://javaconceptoftheday.com/java-inheritance-practice-coding-questions/ , but I am having trouble with questions 2, 3, and 7.

In question 2, since the constructor of object a is B(), why wouldn't it print class B's i value instead of class a's? Instead it prints class a's and I have no idea why.

In question 3, is the reason that the program prints 1 2 3 because there are no constructors and it's just the function? I know when you inherit from a class, you basically act as if all of its functions are in the subclass, so do you basically just pretend class C says:

System.out.println(1);

System.out.println(2);

System.out.println(3);?

In question 7, since the constructor is a C() constructor, why does it still go through the code in the constructor for class A and class B?

Thank you for any help you can give, inheritance is just one of the topics I did not cover in my intro to programming class so I'm trying to fill in all of the blanks before fall semester starts.

Code for question 2:

```
class A
{
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A
{
    int i = 20;
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();

        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```

Code for question 3:

```
class A
{
    {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    {
        System.out.println(3);
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Code for question 7:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        System.out.println("Class A Constructor");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        System.out.println("Class B Constructor");
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    public C()
    {
        System.out.println("Class C Constructor");
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please include the questions from the website in your question? (People are less likely to click a link, and if the link ever goes bad this question won't be answerable.)

Comment: 2) basically because you cannot overwrite fields. 3) those are static initializer blocks, I do not know the exact conditions for their execution but the order seems correct, 7) because you still have to set up the fields in `B` and `A`, and they are called via an implicit `super()` which is "inserted" in all three no-arg constructors.

Comment: @GBlodgett thank you for the advice! I updated the question.

Comment: @luk2302 so anytime a class inherits from another class, in its constructor there's a "super()" function that you don't see? (Basically anytime you call the constructor of the subclass, the superclass constructor is called?

Comment: If you do not write `super(...)` or `this(...)` on your own there, then yes there will an "invisible" `super();`, you always have to end up calling a constructor of the parent class.

Comment: @luk2302 gotcha that makes more sense. And then for question 2, why isn't it printing 20 since the constructor is a B()? Or is the first class the one you base it off of when you create a new object using class object_name = new class() ?

Comment: that has nothing to with constructors. You tell the compiler you have an instance of `A` and access its `i`, since fields cannot be overriden you end up getting 20, if you would simply change the type of the variable to `B` and leave the rest as is you would get `10`.

Comment: @luk2302 So anytime you're working with an object using inheritance, you only use the instance of the object, not the constructor? For example if for the code there was a subclass of B called C and I did A object = new C(), and then did System.out.println(object.i), it would still print 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q2)` The polymorphic behavior of the Java language works with methods and not member variables: they designed the language to bind *member variables* at compile time, methods at run-time.

`Q3)` It's called as *[instance initialization block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block)*. Every instance of a subclass implicitly contains an instance of its superclass. So call order is commenced from `class A`, `B` then `C`.

`Q7)` Same reason of `Q3` applies for the question

Comment: This is starting to clear a lot of it up for me, thank you! So say I create an object by doing: A object = new C();, basically object's functions are treated as the functions of C because it is overridden by class C, but its variables are defined by A?

Comment: @vp123 < Yes, it's.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it now. And then conversely, if I create an instance of an object by doing C object = new C();, it's variables AND functions are defined by C, but it still has an invisible super() in its constructor so if class A and class B constructors have System.out.println() in them, it'll print them as well right?

Comment: @vp123, Yes, there are `super()` calls implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you should take a look at Oracle's Java tutorial, mainly the one on [Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) and the one on [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

---

Let's start with Question 2:

```
class A {
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A {
    int i = 20;
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();

        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```

Since `A` and `B` have a member of same name, `B` hides the member in `A`. In essence, an instance of `B` has two members `i`: one from `A`, and one from `B`. Within method `main`, you write `A a = new B();`, i.e. the static type of `a` is `A`, the runtime type of `a` is `B`. When you now access members, the **static** type decides, which member (`A`'s or `B`'s) is selected. Thus, the `i` in `A` is selected. Why is that? If we modify the example a little bit, we see why:

```
class A {
    int i = 100;
}

class B extends A {
    String i = "Hello";
}

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        A a = new B();
        int i = a.i;
        System.out.println(i);

        String s = ((B) a).i;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

([Run it on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/p6dfO6))

In this example, `B` again hides the member `i` in `A`. But this time, the fields have a different type. Nevertheless, whenever you access the member `i` in `A`, you expect an `int`, not a `String`. This is the reason why the static type decides, which member is selected.

---

Question 3:

```
class A {
    {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}

class C extends B {
    {
        System.out.println(3);
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

For this, we need to know three things:

- If there is no constructor provided for a class, it has an implicit default constructor.
- If the first statement in a constructor is neither `this(...)` nor `super(...)`, then it is an implicit `super();`.
- initializers of a class are executed after the superclass-constructor, but before the own constructor.

What can we conclude from those three statements? If we initialize any object, the first thing we have to execute the superclass-constructor. This leads to a constructor-cascade from the type you try to initialize up to `Object`. Thus, we see the output in-order:

```
1
2
3
```

---

Question 7:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("Class A Constructor");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        System.out.println("Class B Constructor");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public C() {
        System.out.println("Class C Constructor");
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

The answer to this question is already answered through my answer to the last question: If the first statement of a constructor is neither `this(...)` nor `super(...)`, it is implicitly `super()`. Thus, from `C`'s constructor we call `B`'s constructor, and from `B`'s constructor, we call `A`'s constructor. So we, again, get the output in Order:

```
Class A Constructor
Class B Constructor
Class C Constructor
```