# Using curly braces inside object initialization block

Tags: java, javafx

Why is it that the function `bind()` exist only when set inside scope curly braces?

```
public void initialize() {

    inputsAreFull = new BooleanBinding() {
        {
            bind();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

IntelliJ automatically recommends `bind()` when inside curly braces, but the function doesn't exist outside of them?

**This won't work:**

```
public void initialize() {

    inputsAreFull = new BooleanBinding() {

        bind();

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Look up double brace initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new BooleanBinding() { ... }` introduces an anonymous child class of `BooleanBinding`.

Now [**`bind`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html#bind-javafx.beans.Observable...-) is a *protected* method, hence it is not allowed to do `inputsAreFull.bind()`.

But bind may be called in the anonymous initializer block `{ ... }`in the child class body.

There is still a remark needed: as the object is not fully initialized at that moment; the code *actually* being executed in the BooleanBinding constructor (compilier takes care of that), the method `bind` should not be overridable. For that one may use a `private` or (here) a `protected final` method.

Comment: nitpick: the anonymous classes' instance initializer block

Answer (score 7):

The syntax you're using is a shortcut for declaring an implementation of type `BooleanBinding`. You're effectively inside a class declaration.

```
public void initialize(){

    inputsAreFull = new BooleanBinding() {
        // This is equivalent to a class level scope for your anonymous class implementation.
        {
            bind();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

You can't randomly invoke methods at a class level without an initializer block. You can test this out by writing...

```
class MyClass extends BooleanBinding {
    bind(); // It's not gonna be very happy with you.

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

IDEOne with running example: http://ideone.com/EERkXB

See also [What is an initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block)

Comment: Thats not a static initializer block, its an instance initializer block

Comment: The syntax rules are much the same, despite my poor wording. Amending now!

Comment: Maybe intereseting for OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block

Comment: I think this answer could be enhanced with a definition/explanation of how the initializer block works compared to a ctor, and why we must use one in this case.

Comment: The main point I think you should add, is that you can't use a ctor because the class is anonymous; in order to create a ctor, you need to use the class name as the method name which is not discoverable at this time. The initializer block provides a workaround to this issue.