# Java order of initialization

Tags: java, initialization

I have encountered a peculiar effect when initializing fields in Java. My code:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Vehicle {

String name;
static Locale locale;
String localeString = locale.toString();
static int number;
int numberVehicle;
String localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;



public Vehicle(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

static{
     locale = Locale.getDefault();
}

{
    numberVehicle = ++number;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Vehicle{" +
            ", name=" + name +
            ", numberOfVehicle=" + numberVehicle +
            ", localSign='" + localSign +'\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

When I initialize 3 cars and print it, I get:

`Vehicle{, name=citroen, numberOfVehicle=1, localSign='pl_PL0'}`

`Vehicle{, name=opel, numberOfVehicle=2, localSign='pl_PL0'}`

`Vehicle{, name=zyguli, numberOfVehicle=3, localSign='pl_PL0'}`

The **numberVehicle** is increased as intended however the **localSign**, which should contain **numberVehicle**: `String localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;` is always with "0' as the `numberVehicle` would not be increased. When I debug it with breakpoints it shows the value to **localSign** is assigned when **numberVehicle** is initialized withh 0. That seems to me strange, because I did assign the correct value in the instance initializiation block

```
{
numberVehicle = ++number;
}
```

As far as I know (also found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413629/13612259 ) initialization blocks are executed prior to constructor, so I do not understand why `String localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;` is executed when **numberVehicle** is not assigned with proper value. I would be grateful if someone could help me by indicating what I have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting down your code to the relevant bits:

```
static int number;
int numberVehicle;
String localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;

{
    numberVehicle = ++number;
}
```

The instance initializer (that increment `number`) is executed after you assign the value to `localSign`, so you read the uninitialized value.

Assignments on field declarations and instance initializers are executed in the order you declare them. So, the code above is equivalent to:

```
int numberVehicle;
String localSign;

{
    localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;
    numberVehicle = ++number;
}
```

(Actually, the contents of the instance initializers are inserted into the constructor, after the implicit/explicit call to the super/self constructor, and before the rest of the body. Your constructor actually becomes:

```
public Vehicle(String name) {
    super();

    // From field and instance initializers.
    localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;
    numberVehicle = ++number;

    // Constructor body.
    this.name = name;
}
```

To fix this, either move the instance initializer before the `String` assignment; or, easier, assign `numberVehicle` on the field:

```
int numberVehicle = ++number;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand what you are trying to do, but why not something like:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Vehicle {

    String name;
    static Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    String localeString = locale.toString();
    static int number;
    int numberVehicle;
    String localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;

    public Vehicle(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    {
       numberVehicle = ++number;
       localSign = localeString + numberVehicle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
            ", name=" + name +
            ", numberOfVehicle=" + numberVehicle +
            ", localSign='" + localSign +'\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that since you have `static int number;` and I cannot see any setter, this value will always be 0. The same goes for `numberOfVehicle` with the difference that one is initialised with the instantiation and the other in a static way.

Comment: I have thought I increase it in initization block, that is executed prior to constructor: {
    numberVehicle = ++number;
} The point I wanted to achieve is to use and understand initialization block, thats why I have not put this into constructor.

Comment: Ok, but at least the Locale assignment can be done directly in the field instead of in a static block.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You need to reassign the value of `localSign` and that should be it

Comment: Thank you! Now it is working as I intended. So the conclusion for me would be that separation of moments of initialization between "regular fields" and intialization block can create such errors.

Comment: The initialization on the `locationSign` field is redundant: `String localSign;`.