# Interface -> anonymous class

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-class

Why does the following code not print `???`?

```
public class TestInterface {
    interface I {};
    I tester = new I() {{System.out.println("???");}};
    static public void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("OGOGO");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
OGOGO
```

- IDE: IntelliJ
- Jave: jdk-14.0.2

Comment: Works for me.  Can you show your actual code?

Comment: The question is rather: Why does that print at all? Can someone explain? What method  is `{System.out.println("???");}` implementing and why is it called? Is it an initializer block?

Comment: It's called an initializer block, and this is not good use of the feature, but it is legal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block @akuzminykh

Comment: @markspace Yeah, thanks. I've just got it to mind as you've posted it too. I know the syntax but kinda never have seen someone implementing one for an anonymous class. ^^

Comment: @akuzminykh Anonymous classes like this are used by some folks, it's called double brace initialization.  It's not a good idea imo though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java

Comment: Message edited with complete actual code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

akuzminykh is right!

When I change to

```
static I tester
```

it prints.

Comment: Why have you posted my suggestion with a comment that it is working? ^^ You can simply mark my answer as the solution and it will be the same information.

Comment: where is that damn button?!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't print because `new I() {{System.out.println("???");}};` is never executed. Notice that you have a *member variable*, a field, no `static`, there. Fields are initialized together with the corresponding instance of the class, here `TestInterface`. If you want it to print something, create an instance of `TestInterface` and its fields will get initialized with what you've specified. Or simply mark it with `static` so it becomes a *class variable* and is initialized when the class itself is initialized.

Comment: Well, new creates an instance. No question - an instance of anonymous class is created. Some people wrote it works (prints "???") for them.

Comment: We used different code.  akuzminykh is correct.  `new` is never executed in your code.