# Java class variable assignment throws error

Tags: java, class, object, variables, attributes

Why I can't define left's and right's next value like this?

```
public class Solution {
    Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    public Node left = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
    public Node right = new Node(Integer.MAX_VALUE, null, null);
    left.next = right;
    right.prev = left;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

class Node {
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    int val;
    public Node(int val, Node prev, Node next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

When I compile this it throws:

```
Solution.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
    left.next = right;
             ^
Solution.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
    right.prev = left;
              ^
```

I have tried to debug this for a while but it doesn't work. I have defined the variables. And the error message is also ambiguous.

Comment: You can't have `left.setNext = right; right.setPrev = left;` at *top level* of the class. Move it to constructor or initialization block.

Comment: *Exceptions* are thrown. These are *compilation errors*, which are *printed,* or *shown.* Not thrown. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: The assignments `left.next = right; right.prev = left;` are not allowed in that scope. Attributes only allowed to have assignments in their declarations (the attribute for the object is assigned by the value when it is created). But for the assignments you made, we can't tell when it will be done. Unlike when you put the assignments in constructor or method definition, we know it will happen when the constructor or method is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
        public Node left = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
        public Node right = new Node(Integer.MAX_VALUE, null, null);
        left.next = right;
        right.prev = left;
        System.out.println("Works good");
    }
}
```

Try this. You are having the code inside the class. It should be inside the constructor or a method. No issue with your assignment.

Comment: Yes, I can define variables in a method, or constructor; I was curious why defining class attributes doesn't work.

Comment: You aren't definig, you are assigning. that's not possible at class top level. You have to either define & initialize (assign) at once, or assign later on inside dedicated scopes like static initializer, constructor or methods.

Comment: @tomday "I was curious why defining class attributes doesn't work" defining works fine. Note that top level of class is for declaring (defining) *what* class can do/store, not *how* it does it. Even when you write at top level `Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();` compiler will silently split it into (A - declaration of field) `Map<Integer, Node> map;` (B - assigning value to field) `map = new HashMap<>();`. The "A" part will be left at top level of the class *but* B part will be moved at start of *each* constructor of your class (after `super` and potential `this(..)` calls).

Comment: @tomday Note that with `left.next = right; right.prev = left;` at top level we don't know when it should be executed. You *probably* want it be executed when you *create* object of your class. But in that case to make your code clearer this should be part of constructor. If you want it to be part of all constructors of that class you can also move it to *initialization block(s)* (wrap it with `{` and `}`).

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, what do you mean by "you can also move it to initialization block(s) (wrap it with { and })."

Comment: @tomday Have a look at [What is an initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987428) (note there are many nice answer there, don't focus only on top/accepted one). Anyway I was referring to non-static initialization block which is code-block at top level of class. Code from such block(s) is "added" at start of all constructors of class containing it. So if you have code which you want to always be executed in any constructor, you can write it once there instead of creating separate method and explicitly calling it in every constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already in the comments, it is not possible in Java to define code at the top level - maybe one exception is to have an instance initializer block or a static initializer block (see my last 2 examples).

Some of the possible solutions to define your `left` and `right` `Node` instances:

#### Constructor with parameters

Here you'll pass the already initialized instances of your `Node` class.

```java
public class SolutionWithSettingInCtor {
    private final Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Node left;
    private final Node right;

    public SolutionWithSettingInCtor(Node left, Node right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Node left = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
        final Node right = new Node(Integer.MAX_VALUE, null, null);
        left.next = right;
        right.prev = left;

        final var solution = new SolutionWithSettingInCtor(left, right);

        System.out.println(solution.left.next);
        System.out.println(solution.right.prev);
    }
}
```

Here, the logic of assigning `left`'s `next` property - and `right`'s `prev` property was also moved outside of `SolutionWithSettingInCtor`'s responsibility. The right place of this logic depends on your business needs -- in the next example I'll put it into the class's responsibility for demonstrative purposes.

#### Constructor With Local Fields Set in C'tor

```java
public class SolutionWithFieldsSetInCtor {
    private final Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Node left;
    private final Node right;

    public SolutionWithFieldsSetInCtor() {
        this.left = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
        this.right = new Node(Integer.MAX_VALUE, null, null);

        this.setUpNodes();
    }

    private void setUpNodes() {
        this.left.next = right;
        this.right.prev = left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var solution = new SolutionWithSettingInCtor(left, right);

        System.out.println(solution.left.next);
        System.out.println(solution.right.prev);
    }
}
```

As you can see, here the Class' constructor is responsible to initialize the `Node` instances and also it set up the relationships between them in the `setUpNodes()` method.

#### Static Initializer Blocks

This solution has some side-effects and maybe this does not fits your needs. Here, the fields are `static` and can be accessed without initializing an instance of your class.

```java
public class SolutionWithStaticInitializerBlock {
    Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    public static Node left;
    public static Node right;

    static {
        left = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
        right = new Node(Integer.MAX_VALUE, null, null);
        left.next = right;
        right.prev = left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SolutionWithStaticInitializerBlock.left.next);
        System.out.println(SolutionWithStaticInitializerBlock.right.prev);
    }
}
```

Please note the `static` block, where the `static` fields are initialized - no constructors or class initialization needed.

#### Initializer Block Without Static Fields

A more restrictive solution, here you need to have all the `Node`s initialized so you can manipulate them in the [instance initializer block](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-instance-initializer-block).

```java
public class SolutionWithSettingWithBlock {
    private final Map<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Node left = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);;
    private final Node right = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);;

    {
        left.next = right;
        right.prev = left;
    }
    public SolutionWithSettingWithBlock() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var solution = new SolutionWithSettingWithBlock();

        System.out.println(solution.left.next);
        System.out.println(solution.right.prev);
    }
}
```

What is the best solution depends on your needs, but now you have some Solutions (pun intended).

Comment: Don't mix up defining and initializing. You can define properties at class level.

Comment: @Slevin thanks, I rephrased my answer. Please feel free to edit it, I am not 100% satisfied with that sentence.