# Allocate a double-String-Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string

I want to create a new String[][] Array but eclipse gives me an error:

```
public class CurriculumVitae {

String[][] education = new String[2][6]; //throws error here and expects "{" but why?
education[0][0] = "10/2012 − heute";
education[0][1] = "Studium der Informatik";
education[0][2] = "Johannes Gutenberg−Universit \\”at Mainz";
education[0][3] = "";
education[0][4] = "";
education[0][5] = "";
education[1][0] = "10/2005 − 5/2012";
education[1][1] = "Abitur";
education[1][2] = "Muppet-Gymnasium";
education[1][3] = "Note: 1,3";
education[1][4] = "";
education[1][5] = "";}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"

Comment: initializing values must have defining that kinds of data-structure.(Arrays)Because of that,you should use constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration is ok.

However you must use an initializer block for assigning your `array` values.

Just enclose all `education[x][y]` statements within curly brackets, or move them to the constructor.

- Initializer block example

  ```
  public class CurriculumVitae {
      String[][] education = new String[2][6];
      // initializer block
      {
          education[0][0] = "10/2012 − heute";
          education[0][1] = "Studium der Informatik";
      }
  }
  ```
- Constructor example

  ```
  public class CurriculumVitae {

      String[][] education = new String[2][6];
      // constructor
      public CurriculumVitae()
      {
          education[0][0] = "10/2012 − heute";
          education[0][1] = "Studium der Informatik";
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you, i think i always had those arrays in methods before and not as global values in a class.

Comment: @Mena is %100 right :) I said same words on the above of this post.

Comment: which methods looks more smooth regarding coding conventions? an initializer or a constructor?

Comment: @Tak3r07 take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804589/use-of-initializers-vs-constructors-in-java)!

Answer (score 0):

you code must be inside a method. For Example:

```
public class CurriculumVitae {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[][] education = new String[2][6];
    education[0][0] = "10/2012 − heute";
    education[0][1] = "Studium der Informatik";
    education[0][2] = "Johannes Gutenberg−Universit \\”at Mainz";
    education[0][3] = "";
    education[0][4] = "";
    education[0][5] = "";
    education[1][0] = "10/2005 − 5/2012";
    education[1][1] = "Abitur";
    education[1][2] = "Muppet-Gymnasium";
    education[1][3] = "Note: 1,3";
    education[1][4] = "";
    education[1][5] = "";
  }
}
```