# Why do I need to `{...}` to filling an array in the class scope?

Tags: java

What's wrong with the below program?

```
package test;

public class Test {

    byte[] array = new byte[2];
    array[0] = 'A';
    array[1] = 'B';
}
```

Look,the IDE indicate some problems(click to enlarge) :

[image]

In the other word, why should I move the filler lines to another inner scope as follow :

```
package test;

public class Test {

    byte[] array = new byte[2];
    {
        array[0] = 'A';
        array[1] = 'B';
    }
}
```

The IDE doesn't have any problem with above program.

Comment: With `array[0] = 'A';` you're not initializing a new variable, you are filling an existing array. I'm not a Java export but it don't surprize me you can't do it in class description as a new initialization.

Comment: Screenshots of an IDE are a lousy way to share code. Try to find somewhere in your IDE (for example, the compiler output window) where you can grab the error messages as text to include in your question.

Comment: The answer is... because the JLS defines it so. You can have a look at the JLS 8.1.6 - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6. Also as a side note you could simply use an array initializer here (which is valid), i.e `byte[] array = {'A', 'B'}`;

Comment: @AndrewJanke I can't see this kind of error messages any where else. In the compiler output window, I can only see compile time errors

Comment: @Abraham This is a compile time error, like all syntax errors. The IDE is just doing a partial compile in the background so it can give you that syntax advice. Manually tell it to do a full build of your file or project, and you should see the errors in the Console output or a similar window. One of those toolbar buttons, or menu item (maybe under Project or File), or an item in a context menu you get from right-clicking on the class in the Package Explorer should do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in this snippet you try to do some assignments (to the array: e.g. `array[0] = 'A'`) outside any method

```
public class Test {
    byte[] array = new byte[2];
    array[0] = 'A';
    array[1] = 'B';
}
```

whereas in this snippet you do the assignments inside the instance initializer block

```
public class Test {
    byte[] array = new byte[2];
    {
        array[0] = 'A';
        array[1] = 'B';
    }
}
```

if you want to do it in your code you could do it for example in an init method

```
public class Test {
    byte[] array = new byte[2];

    void initArray() {
        array[0] = 'A';
        array[1] = 'B';
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the answer is : My first snippet is wrong because Java language defined in a way  that we can't assign values to arrays elements in this way in the class scope, and we must move these assignments inside a method or inside instance initializer block (**i.e. `{...}` ?**). **Right?** (And also I can use `byte[] array = {'A', 'B'}; ` instead)

Comment: @Abraham Your're absolutely right with both assumptions. And doing the declaration and assignment in one line `byte[] array = {'A', 'B'};` is a common way (for simple assignments).

Comment: @vikingsteve There is no example for the `static initializer` block. The use itself depends on the case. But I agree it should not be overused if another approach suites better (to be avoided: long lasting initialisation, initialize havy weight objects, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The `{....}` in your example are called [initialization blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). They are used to  to set the value of "final" static variables whereas a constructor cannot. In your case you dont need them, you could well initialize your array in your constructor.

The reason why it is not working in the first place without the initializers is because it is simply not valid java syntax.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804589/use-of-initializers-vs-constructors-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor) for more info

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to using an *instance initializer* block, you could do what you want in a neat one-liner, like this:

```
// much better, and much smaller
public class Test {
    byte[] array = {'A', 'B'};
}
```

Comment: *"Please don't use static initializer blocks wherever possible."* .. he isn't using one, so everything is alright.

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html and see the difference between a _static initializer block_ and an _instance initializer block_.