# JavaFX Application class - difference between default constructor and init method

Tags: java, javafx

I have written a little test application that looks like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    public Test() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("second");
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("third");
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("fourth");
        super.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

Now, I am asking myself where the difference is between using the default constructor or the `init` method for initialising some required things.

Thanks!

P.S.: This question is not duplicate with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804589/use-of-initializers-vs-constructors-in-java), because my issue does not handle the initialisation of variables. My question is `JavaFX` specific!

Comment: Possibly the only difference is that in `init` you can get the parameters - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the `Application` is launched, the following steps are executed during the launch process:

1. The instance of the `Application` subclass that should be launched is created. (Constructor is called)
2. The `init()` of that instance is called.
3. The `start` method of that instance is called.

[See javadoc for `Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Since you [exit the application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--) after the `start` method is called, the `stop` method of the instance is called.

Note that there is no need to use `super.init()` and `super.stop()`:

From the javadoc

> The `init` and `stop` methods have concrete implementations that do nothing.

The differences of constructor, `init` and `start` are:

#### Constructor

If your application is not `final` the application class could be extended. Since the constructor of the extending class is not complete, it may be dangerous to pass a reference to the class to other classes in this state. Also the instance hasn't been initialized to a point where the `getParameters` method returns the parameters.

#### `init`

Initialisation should generally be done in this method. This method isn't run from the fx application thread, so some things cannot be done from this method, like creating a `Stage`.

#### `start`

Last step in the initialisation. Do things that require to be run from the application thread here. Be careful not to block this thread with long-runing operations however, since this freezes the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

> difference is between using the default constructor or the init

`init` runs on a separate thread.

## Threading

See the [*Threading*](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) section of the Javadoc.

The `main` method of any Java app executes on an initial thread assigned to that app.

In a JavaFX app, the construction of your `Application` subclass occurs on another thread, a thread named *JavaFX Application Thread*. This thread is the event-dispatching thread for your JavaFX app. Any `Stage` and `Scene` objects, and their contained JavaFX objects, must only be accessed and manipulated from this particular thread.

After construction of your `Application` subclass, the JavaFX framework automatically invokes the `Application#init` on yet another thread, a third thread, a “launcher thread”.

While that `init` method executes on the other thread, the JavaFX framework executes the `Application#start` method. The crucial point here is that `start` runs *alongside* `init`, *not after* `init` completes. The execution of `init` and `start` can overlap in time.

So at least *three* threads are involved in getting your JavaFX/OpenJFX app going.

---

See a my table of sequence steps of a JavaFX app’s lifecycle in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76800602/642706) on a related Question.

Answer (score -1):

Application Class having init() method which you have override.
The Init method will call immediately after the Test class construction.
Init method is actually an internal method of Application Class. This method is actually initialize the whole FX application components internally.

[Application class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

it may construct other JavaFX objects in this method.

Comment: Everything you say here is also true for the constructor.