# Listview issue in javafx

Tags: java, postgresql, list, listview, javafx

I have a javafx project. In the main view i have a listview with some tags item and a delete button. The whole project is connected to a postgresql db. The tags are stored as ( user_id, name, color). When i click the delete button, the tag is deleted from the db, but i get this error "No results were returned by the query." while i have items in db and the list is updated. Why do i keep getting this error?

```
public class TagsController extends SQLConnection implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public Button forest, shop, timeline, tags, rewards, settings, friends, button;
    @FXML
    public VBox menu, vbox;
    @FXML
    public Label gold;

    @FXML
    public ListView<Tag> listView;


    public Stage stage;
    public Scene scene;

    ObservableList<Tag> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    List<Tag> listOfTags;

    {
        try {
            listOfTags = new ArrayList<>(listOfTags());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    User user = new User();



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        //set the gold value
        gold.setText(String.valueOf(getGold(user.getId())));

        //set the image of the menu button
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/menu.png");
        Image image = new Image(in);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        button.setGraphic(imageView);
        button.setMaxSize(40, 40);
        button.setMinSize(40, 40);
        button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);
        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(button.widthProperty());
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        //hide the menu buttons
        forest.setVisible(false);
        shop.setVisible(false);
        timeline.setVisible(false);
        tags.setVisible(false);
        rewards.setVisible(false);
        settings.setVisible(false);
        friends.setVisible(false);
        menu.setVisible(false);

        listView.setItems(list);

        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
            private final Button deleteButton = new Button();


            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Tag tag, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(tag, empty);

                if (empty || tag == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(tag.getName());
                    setGraphic(deleteButton);
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #deaef4; -fx-padding: 20px; -fx-border-width: 1px; -fx-border-color: #cccccc; -fx-font-family: System Italic; -fx-font-size: 19; -fx-text-fill: #f5f599;");


                    InputStream in1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/bin.png");
                    Image image1 = new Image(in1);
                    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image1);
                    imageView1.setFitHeight(40);
                    imageView1.setFitWidth(40);
                    deleteButton.setGraphic(imageView1);
                    deleteButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #deaef4;");

                    deleteButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {

                        removeTag(user.getId(), tag.getName());
                        list.remove(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                        listView.getItems().remove(tag);
                        refreshTags();
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        refreshTags();

    }

    private void refreshTags(){

        listView.getItems().removeAll();
        list.removeAll();
        try {
            Connection connection = connection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE user_id = " + user.getId();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultSet.next()) {

                listView.getItems().add(new Tag(
                        user.getId(),
                        resultSet.getString("name"),
                        resultSet.getString("color"))
                );
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question appears to be a database question which has nothing to do with UI.  Yes, I know your class has both database and UI code in it, but it really should not.  A JavaFX controller should not extend an SQLConnection.  Practice [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  Write and [test](https://junit.org/junit5/) your database code independent of the UI.

Comment: @jewelsea the controller extends the SQLConnection because in that class i have a lot of functions that retrieve data. Because i had problems i chose to first try and resolve the problem, then move the database code. I did tests and those passed.

Comment: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=java%20repository%20pattern

Comment: There should be no need to call `refreshItems()` in the handler for the delete button. Simply removing the tag from the list view should update it.

Comment: @James_D the item is deleted successfully from the list view and database, after that there are still remaining data in db but i get that error and i do not know why.

Comment: If you don’t know why, and you can see the code, there’s very little chance anyone here can tell you when we can only see code snippets. What is the complete stack trace (post it in the question, formatted as code)? Which exact lines in your code are generating the error? Why are you calling `refreshItems()` when there is no need to?

Comment: *"the controller extends the SQLConnection because in that class i have a lot of functions that retrieve data"* But that's exactly the point being made. Your UI classes (such as the controller) should not have database code in. Separate these out into separate classes so that you can test each one independently.

Comment: Also, what you are doing here just doesn't make sense. Replacing all the data in the list view (which `refreshTags()` does) will likely cause `updateItem()` to be called on all the list view cells. Then your `updateItem()` methods call `refreshTags()`. This will (or at least has the potential to) cause every cell to create a database request on every frame rendering (60 times per second). You need to completely restructure this.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working too hard. The point of using `ObservableList` is that when you add or delete to that collection, the subscribed listener objects will be informed of the change. So there is no need for you to replacing all elements. Just delete the selected `Tag` object from the observable list, and the `ListView` will update itself automatically. See example code below.

As discussed in the Comments, your code needs to be re-organized.

To make your code more comprehensible, learn to think in terms of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Each piece of code should have one [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

So… Code for interacting with the user should not know anything about SQL and databases. Code for managing the lifecycle of your app (launching, exiting, etc.) should not know the details of the forms appearing in your user-interface. And so on.

Let's write a revamped example. Here we define a simple `Tag` class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import java.util.UUID;

public record Tag( String title , UUID id ) {}
```

In your app, the key re-org is separating the database work from the user-interface (UI) work. In the Java world, we commonly seen this done via the *Repository* pattern. Define an interface with features needed by your app for interacting with a database.

In our case with this example, we need just two operations:

- Fetch all `Tag` objects.
- Delete a single `Tag` object.

So our interface looks like this:

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import java.util.List;

public interface Repository
{
    List < Tag > fetchAllTags ( );

    boolean deleteTag ( final Tag tag );
}
```

One advantage of using an interface here is that we can write a simple hard-coded implementation using an in-memory collection of `Tag` objects. No need to get distracted by messy SQL code now. We can develop our UI without any database involvement.

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Repository_ListBacked implements Repository
{
    // Member fields.
    private final List < Tag > tags =
            new ArrayList <>(
                    List.of(
                            new Tag( "Alice" , UUID.fromString( "be5abd37-e737-440d-b6f6-43ba88612574" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Bob" , UUID.fromString( "cd8443ac-c0f8-4a7f-b864-6ee5bb6bd0a4" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Carol" , UUID.fromString( "798c300e-2733-46e7-a8b2-cee2cc48afd5" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Davis" , UUID.fromString( "f7711c12-0f7f-470e-9fbe-c0f1cfb8f848" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Edith" , UUID.fromString( "57f7352f-e705-49ac-b62e-07f1d8ae5341" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "François" , UUID.fromString( "5b257c5e-b79f-46b8-b056-133f984cdc2f" ) )
                    )
            );

    // Constructors.
    public Repository_ListBacked ( ) { }

    // Implements Repository interface.
    @Override
    public List < Tag > fetchAllTags ( ) { return List.copyOf( this.tags ); }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteTag ( final Tag tag ) { return this.tags.remove( tag ); }
}
```

Now we can build our UI to use this hard-coded repository. Our entire UI for displaying and deleting tags is contained in its own class. This class extends one of the JavaFX layout managers.

Our class here fetches `Tag` objects from the repository. Those `Tag` objects are then transferred to an observable list. We use that observable list to back a `ListView` widget.

This UI class will need to interact with an instance of `Repository`. We pass an instance to the UI class constructor. This is one way of doing [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), supplying a needed resource or service without the consuming class from having to know how to get it or where it came from.

Notice how the Delete button uses the `Repository` object to:

- Populate its `ListView`
- Delete the `Tag` object of the selected row.

As a nicety, we enable/disable our Delete button as the user selects/deselects a row. Notice how we add a selection listener to make that happen.

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Objects;

public class TagListEditorLayout extends VBox
{
    private final Repository repository;

    public TagListEditorLayout ( final Repository repository )
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.create( );
    }

    private void create ( )
    {
        // Widgets
        ObservableList < Tag > tags = FXCollections.observableArrayList( this.repository.fetchAllTags( ) );
        ListView < Tag > tagsListView = new ListView <>( tags );
        tagsListView.setCellFactory( new TagCellFactory( ) );

        Button deleteButton = new Button( "Delete" );
        deleteButton.setDisable( true );

        // Behavior

        // Enable button when a Tag element of list view is selected. Otherwise, disable Delete button.
        tagsListView.getSelectionModel( ).selectedItemProperty( ).addListener(
                ( ObservableValue < ? extends Tag > _ , Tag previouslySelectedTag , Tag newlySelectedTag ) ->
                        deleteButton.setDisable( Objects.isNull( newlySelectedTag ) )
        );

        deleteButton.setOnAction(
                ( ActionEvent event ) -> {
                    System.out.println( event );  // Debug.
                    Tag tag = tagsListView.getSelectionModel( ).selectedItemProperty( ).get( );
                    if ( Objects.nonNull( tag ) )
                    {
                        if ( repository.deleteTag( tag ) )
                        {
                            tags.remove( tag );
                            System.out.println( this.repository.fetchAllTags( ) );  // Debug.
                        } else
                        {
                            System.out.println( "ERROR Repository failed to delete tag, so we interrupted response to user clicking Delete button. " + Instant.now( ) );
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        System.out.println( "ERROR Should not be reachable. Delete button should work only if a Tag element is selected in list view. " + Instant.now( ) );
                    }
                }
        );

        // Arrange
        this.getChildren( ).addAll( tagsListView , deleteButton );
        this.setSpacing( 10 );
        this.setPadding( new Insets( 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 ) );
    }

    static class TagCellFactory implements Callback < ListView < Tag >, ListCell < Tag > >
    {
        @Override
        public ListCell < Tag > call ( ListView < Tag > param )
        {
            return new ListCell <>( )
            {
                @Override
                public void updateItem ( Tag tag , boolean empty )
                {
                    super.updateItem( tag , empty );
                    if ( empty || tag == null )
                    {
                        setText( null );
                    } else
                    {
                        setText( tag.title( ) );
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Look at how we respond to a button click. First we delete the matching object from our repository. The crucial part is how that deletion method returns a boolean to indicate success or failure. If successful, only then do we delete from our observable list. After deleting from the observable list, the `ListView` object automatically updates its display to omit the removed item.

And we need to harness all this code to make an app. We do this here by writing a class named `App` that extends from the JavaFX `Application` class. This `App` class manages the lifecycle of a JavaFX app, by overriding methods such as `start` and `stop`.

Notice how we instantiate a particular implementation of `Repository`. Then we instantiate our layout, a `TagListEditorLayout` object, and wrap into a `Scene` (viewport of window) placed in a `Stage` (window).

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Objects;

public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void init ( )
    {
        // For more info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76800602/642706
        String message = "INFO - The `App#init` method is running on separate thread " + Thread.currentThread( ).threadId( ) + " “" + Thread.currentThread( ).getName( ) + "”" + " at " + Instant.now( );
        System.out.println( message );
    }

    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage )
    {
        String message = ( "INFO - The `App#start` method is running on JavaFX Application thread " + Thread.currentThread( ).threadId( ) + " “" + Thread.currentThread( ).getName( ) + "”" + " at " + Instant.now( ) );
        System.out.println( message );

        // -------------|  Resources  |---------------------------
        Repository repository = new Repository_ListBacked( );  

        // -------------|  GUI  |---------------------------
        Parent parent = new TagListEditorLayout( repository );
        Scene scene = new Scene( parent , 320 , 240 );
        stage.setTitle( "Tags Editor" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show( );
    }

    @Override
    public void stop ( ) throws Exception
    {
        String message = ( "INFO - The `App#stop` method is running on JavaFX Application thread " + Thread.currentThread( ).threadId( ) + " “" + Thread.currentThread( ).getName( ) + "”" + " at " + Instant.now( ) );
        System.out.println( message );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        javafx.application.Application.launch( );
    }
}
```

Now we can run our app. Select a row to enable the Delete button.

[image: screenshot of demo app]

Hit the Delete button to try our logic. You should see the selected row disappear as we delete the `Tag` object from the observable list.

Great! It all works. But what you *really* wanted was database access. So we need another implementation of `Repository` to work with a database. Here we use the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(database)), for convenience.

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Repository_H2 implements Repository
{
    // Member fields.
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    // Constructors.
    public Repository_H2 ( final DataSource dataSource ) { this.dataSource = dataSource; }

    // Implements `Repository`.
    @Override
    public List < Tag > fetchAllTags ( )
    {
        String sql = """
                SELECT * FROM tag_ 
                ;
                """;
        ArrayList < Tag > tags = new ArrayList <>( );
        try (
                Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( ) ;
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            while ( resultSet.next( ) )
            {
                UUID id = resultSet.getObject( "id_" , UUID.class );
                String title = resultSet.getString( "title_" );
                Tag tag = new Tag( title , id );
                tags.add( tag );
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
        tags.trimToSize( );
        return List.copyOf( tags );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteTag ( final Tag tag )
    {
        boolean deletionSuccessful = false;
        String sql = """
                DELETE FROM tag_ 
                WHERE id_ = ?
                ;
                """;

        try
                (
                        Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
                )
        {
            Objects.requireNonNull( tag );
            UUID id = Objects.requireNonNull( tag.id( ) );
            preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , id );
            int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate( );
            deletionSuccessful = ( rowsAffected > 0 );
            if ( deletionSuccessful )
            {
                System.out.println( "INFO - Successfully deleted `tag_` row for ID: " + id + " at " + Instant.now( ) );
            } else
            {
                System.out.println( "ERROR - No `tag_` row` deleted for id: " + id + " at " + Instant.now( ) );
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
        return deletionSuccessful;
    }
}
```

And change our `App` class to use this alternative `Repository` implementation.

```java
        // -------------|  Resources  |---------------------------
//        Repository repository = new Repository_ListBacked( );  // Can be swapped for `Repository_H2`.

        DataSource dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( Environment.fetchDataSourceForH2( ) );
        new DatabasePrep_H2( dataSource ).prepare( );
        Repository repository = new Repository_H2( dataSource );
```

At this point, we can more easily debug any database problems. We know our app worked perfectly well without any database. So if we experience any problems, we know it comes from our database work. (Indeed, we could even write separate code to test our database access code without using our UI at all. But for now, let's try our UI code.)

Notice in code above that we use a `DataSource` object to store our database login credentials, such as user name, user password, the name of the database, the server address, and so on. Using `DataSource` gives you flexibility later, letting you externalize these details outside your source code. For example, a `DataSource` object can be retrieved from a naming/directory service such as an LDAP server. This way, you don't need to recompile your app just for a password change.

Here's class to mimic retrieving a `DataSource` object.

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

// To interact with the host OS, and with network environs such as naming/directory services.
public class Environment
{
   static DataSource fetchDataSourceForH2 ( )
    {
        // In real work, a `DataSource` implementation would come from a naming/directory service such as LDAP server rather than hard-coding.
        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = new org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource( );
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:ex_fx_listview_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
        return ds;
    }

}
```

Of course we need to also set up a database. So write a class for that. This class creates the database, creates our `tag_` table, and populates that tables with some example data.

In real work, I would use a [database migration tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) like [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) to run SQL scripts to create the tables and pre-populate rows.

```java
package work.basil.example.exfxlistview;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DatabasePrep_H2
{
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public DatabasePrep_H2 ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    void prepare ( )
    {
        this.createTagTable( );
        this.populateTagTable( );
    }

    private void createTagTable ( )
    {
        String sql = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag_ 
                ( 
                    id_ UUID PRIMARY KEY , 
                    title_ VARCHAR( 255 ) 
                ) 
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( )
        )
        {
            statement.execute( sql );
            System.out.println( "Table created successfully." );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "Error creating table: " + e.getMessage( ) );
        }
    }

    private void populateTagTable ( )
    {
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO tag_ ( id_ , title_ ) 
                VALUES ( ? , ? )
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql )
        )
        {
            // Inserting multiple rows using batch processing
            final List < Tag > tags =
                    List.of(
                            new Tag( "Alice" , UUID.fromString( "be5abd37-e737-440d-b6f6-43ba88612574" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Bob" , UUID.fromString( "cd8443ac-c0f8-4a7f-b864-6ee5bb6bd0a4" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Carol" , UUID.fromString( "798c300e-2733-46e7-a8b2-cee2cc48afd5" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Davis" , UUID.fromString( "f7711c12-0f7f-470e-9fbe-c0f1cfb8f848" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "Edith" , UUID.fromString( "57f7352f-e705-49ac-b62e-07f1d8ae5341" ) ) ,
                            new Tag( "François" , UUID.fromString( "5b257c5e-b79f-46b8-b056-133f984cdc2f" ) )
                    );
            for ( Tag tag : tags )
            {
                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , tag.id( ) );
                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , tag.title( ) );
                preparedStatement.addBatch( );
            }
            int[] affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeBatch( );
            System.out.println( "Rows inserted successfully. Affected rows: " + affectedRows.length );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "Error inserting rows: " + e.getMessage( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

And, voilà, we have fully functioning database-backed list editor.

Later, in further development, if you started having problems, you could always switch back to the list-backed repository to eliminate the database from your debugging considerations.

---

For completeness, here is my `POM` & `module-info.java`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExFxListView</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExFxListView</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--        Remove JavaFX dependency if using a JVM that comes bundled with OpenJFX libraries. -->
        <!--        Otherwise, enable dependency.-->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>22</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>22</source>
                    <target>22</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.example.exfxlistview/work.basil.example.exfxlistview.App</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```java
module work.basil.example.exfxlistview {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires java.naming;
    requires java.sql;
    requires com.h2database;

    exports work.basil.example.exfxlistview;
}
```