# Order of field initialization

Tags: java

Consider the following example:

```
public class Constructor
{
     Constructor(int i)
     {
            System.out.println(i);
     }
}

public class Test
{

       Constructor c1 = new Constructor(1);

       Constructor c2 = new Constructor(2);

       public static void main(String[] args)
       { 
           new Test();
       }
}
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
```

Please explain why this happens and whether this behavior is consistent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804589/use-of-initializers-vs-constructors-in-java

Comment: Read the Fine Manual: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: You should avoid the use of type names for custom types that match Java API type names, _especially_ names from `java.lang` and its subpackages, _especially_ especially well-known and widely used type names like `Constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

The initializers for static and instance fields are class are executed in the order that they appear in the source code.

In your example, the `c1` declaration is before the `c2` declaration, so it is executed first, and indicated by the output you see.

Why?

1. Because the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) says so:

   > "4) Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, *in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class*."

   (If that doesn't make sense to you, refer to the JLS to read the sentence in its context.)
2. Because it makes sense to do it that way:

   - an unspecified order of initialization would be bad for code portability,
   - any other order (e.g. reverse order, lexical order) would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: but ponit   Class Test  "new Test()"   not  Class Constructor

Comment: Yes.  But `Test` declares `c1` and `c2` and initializes them using `new Constructor(...)`.  My answer explains *what happens* when you `new Test()`.  And what happens is that those two `Constructor` instances are created.